# How to determine the type of spline in GAM?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model, splines

I want to model a variable in the form of

```
fit <- gam(y ~ x + s(z,k=-1,bs=?))
```

To let the function decide the ideal number of knots, I am using k=-1 but I am not able to figure out what type of spline to use. I have added a plot below. Please advise or if possible direct me to sources where I can learn about it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation for the `mgcv` package, there is a [page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html) describing the spline-based smoothers available. Moreover Wood (the package author) offers the following advice:

> Broadly speaking the default penalized thin plate regression splines
>   tend to give the best MSE performance, but they are slower to set up
>   than the other bases.

Since in your case you have less than 200 data points, so I don't think you will run into computational issues with the default method. In section 4.1 of Wood's book "Generalized Additive Models: an introduction with R", he has a summary of the major smoothing bases (Thin plate regression splines, Duchon splines, Cubic regression splines, P-splines) available in `mgcv` along with a discussion of their merits and other practical considerations. I have found the book quite helpful in developing my understanding of GAMs.